# how can I c++ linked list iterator compare to two data

Tags: c++, iterator

```
for(iter = a.begin();iter != a.end();++iter) {
    
    if(differ(*iter,*(++iter)) > 0){
        cout << "unchange order" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "change order" << endl;
    }
```

I made a linked list and am using an iterator to compare to two objects.  Linked list with two data objects print right information, however, for more than two data in linked list, it prints just one line and does not print more than two lines. I changed code to `differ(*iter,*(iter++)` but this code does not print right results. How can I solve this?

differ function is this:

```
int differ(string a, string b){
    int num_1;
    int num_2;
    int pos = 0;
    if(a.find("S") != string::npos)
        num_1 = 10 + stoi(a.substr(1));
    else if(a.find("D") != string::npos)
        num_1 = 23 + stoi(a.substr(1));
    else if(a.find("H") != string::npos)
        num_1 = 36 + stoi(a.substr(1));
    else if(a.find("C") != string::npos)
        num_1 = 49 + stoi(a.substr(1));

    if(b.find("S") != string::npos)
        num_2 = 10 + stoi(b.substr(1));
    else if(b.find("D") != string::npos)
        num_2 = 23 + stoi(b.substr(1));
    else if(b.find("H") != string::npos)
        num_2 = 36 + stoi(b.substr(1));
    else if(b.find("C") != string::npos)
        num_2 = 49 + stoi(b.substr(1));


    return num_2 - num_1;
```

two random string to int function

chain code is this

```
template<class U> class Chain;

template <class T> class ChainNode {
    template<class U> friend class Chain;
    private:
        T data;
        ChainNode *link;
    public:
        ChainNode(T d, ChainNode * l) : data(d), link(l) {}
};

template <class T> class Chain {
    private:
        ChainNode<T> *first;

    public:
        Chain() {first = 0;}; // first를 0으로 초기화하는 생성자
        // 체인 조작 연산들
        void push(T data){
            first = new ChainNode<T>(data, first);
        }
        class iterator{
            ChainNode<T> *current;
            public:
                iterator(ChainNode<T> *p) : current(p) {}
                // 연산자 오버로등 iterator의 동작을 수행
                iterator& operator++() {
                    current = current->link;
                    return *this;
                }
                iterator operator++(int){
                    iterator old = *this;
                    current = current->link;
                    return old;
                }
                T &operator*() {return current->data;}
                bool operator !=(const iterator t) {return current != t.current;}
                bool operator ==(const iterator t) {return current == t.current;}

        };
    iterator begin(){
        return iterator(first);

    }

    iterator end(){
        return iterator(NULL);
    }

        
};
```

and push data code is this

```
while(1){
    /* 세번째 카드 뽑는 과정 */
random_device thr;
mt19937 mersenn_1(thr());
uniform_int_distribution<int> symbol_2(1,4);
symbol_num = symbol_2(mersenn_1);

if(symbol_num == 1)
    sym = "S";
else if(symbol_num == 2)
    sym = "D";
else if(symbol(mersenne) == 3)
    sym = "H";
else if(symbol_num == 4)
    sym = "C";


random_device two_2; 
mt19937 me_1(two_2());
uniform_int_distribution<> num_2(1,13);
card_num = num_2(me_1);

input_3 = sym + to_string(card_num);

if(input_3 == input_1 || input_3 == input_2){
    continue;
}
else{
    break;
}
}

cout << "\n" << "3번째 숫자는 " << input_3 << endl;

a.push(input_3);
```

printed this

1번째 숫자는 C6
C6

2번째 숫자는 S9
S9 C6
unchange orde

3번째 숫자는 C10
C10 S9 C6
change order

Comment: Try changing to `if(differ(*iter,*(iter + 1)) > 0){`.

Comment: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Chain<string>::iterator' and 'int') chain is string type... omg...

Comment: Please post the complete code (a [mre]) and the complete error message.

Comment: I Edit minimal example code..

Answer (score 0):

So I think the issue here is that you have iter++ at the end of your for loop and also in as an argument for differ, which means it will move forwards twice per loop rather than once. It will also go one past the end at the back I think.
A simple way around this would be just to store the previous value:

```
string prev=*a.begin();
for(iter = a.begin()+1;iter != a.end();++iter) {
    
    if(differ(*iter,prev) > 0){
        cout << "unchange order" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "change order" << endl;
    }
    prev=*iter;
}
```

You could also duplicate the iterator to another variable and move that one forward once, to get the next entry.